# Aggregate Pandas DataFrame based on condition that uses multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "K": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
    "LABEL": ["X123", "X123", "X21", "L31", "L31"],
    "VALUE": [1, 3, 1, 2, 5.0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

output = """
   K LABEL  VALUE
0  A   X12    1.0
1  A   X12    3.0
2  B   X21    1.0
3  B   L31    2.0
4  B   L31    5.0
"""
```

## Transformation steps

For each group ( grouped by K ), find FINAL_VALUE defined below.

Where LABEL are or two types X__ and L__

```
# if LABEL is X___ then FINAL_VALUE = sum(VALUE)
# if LABEL is L___ then FINAL_VALUE = count(VALUE)
# else FINAL_VALUE = 0
```

Result of transformation

```
expected_output = """
K  LABEL  FINAL_VALUE
A    X12            4
B    X21            1
B    L31            2
"""
```

How can I achieve this using Pandas ?

**EDIT1**: Partially working

```
In [17]: df.groupby(["K", "LABEL"]).agg({"VALUE": {"VALUE_SUM": "sum", "VALUE_COUNT": "count"}})
Out[17]: 
              VALUE          
        VALUE_COUNT VALUE_SUM
K LABEL                      
A X12             2       4.0
B L31             2       7.0
  X21             1       1.0
```

**EDIT2:** Using `reset_index()` to fill up the dataframe

```
In [18]: df2 = df.groupby(["K", "LABEL"]).agg({"VALUE": {"VALUE_SUM": "sum", "VALUE_COUNT": "count"}})

In [21]: df2.reset_index()
Out[21]: 
   K LABEL       VALUE          
           VALUE_COUNT VALUE_SUM
0  A   X12           2       4.0
1  B   L31           2       7.0
2  B   X21           1       1.0
```

**EDIT3:** Final solution using `df.apply()`

```
In [59]: df3 = df2.reset_index()

In [60]: df3["FINAL_VALUE"] = df3.apply(lambda x: x["VALUE"]["VALUE_SUM"] if x["LABEL"].str.startswith("X").any() else x["VALUE"]["VALUE_COUNT"] , axis=1)

In [61]: df3[["K", "LABEL", "FINAL_VALUE"]]
Out[61]: 
   K LABEL FINAL_VALUE

0  A   X12         4.0
1  B   L31         2.0
2  B   X21         1.0
```

Comment: OK, I see that you already got the answer by yourself:)

Comment: @vlad.rad Not yet :-) I am almost there. I need to get the exact columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`DFGroupby.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) like you have done before followed by writing a generic function which computes the necessary requirements with the help of [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and returns the required frame as shown:

```
def compute_multiple_condition(row):
    if row['LABEL'].startswith('X'):
        return row['sum']
    elif row['LABEL'].startswith('L'):
          return row['count']
    else:
        return 0

df = df.groupby(['K','LABEL'])['VALUE'].agg({'sum': 'sum', 'count': 'count'}).reset_index()
df['FINAL_VALUE'] = df.apply(compute_multiple_condition, axis=1).astype(int)
df = df[['K', 'LABEL', 'FINAL_VALUE']]
df

   K LABEL  FINAL_VALUE
0  A   X12            4
1  B   L31            2
2  B   X21            1
```

Comment: For me `startswith` gave the error: `AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'startswith'", u'occurred at index 0')`. But you gave the right approach.

Comment: You need to use it along with the `str` accessor like `series.str.startswith()`. In my function, it is calculated on individual strings and not on the entire series as such and hence the accessor isn't required.

Comment: Also, check the `dtypes`. `LABEL` column should be of type `object` for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

you can try data frame chain:

```
result = (df.groupby(['K', 'LABEL'])
            .apply(lambda frame: frame.VALUE.sum() 
                                if frame.LABEL.iloc[0].startswith("X") else len(frame))
            .to_frame()
            .rename({'0': 'FINAL_VALUE'})
         )
```